# replace or delete javascript tag for another before load content

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace specific script tag `<script>` for another script tag `<script>` before load content html. I mean, I don't want to load this javascript, since it is advertising.

**Replace this** `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://site.net/c/banner_s?tenant=AD&selection=5986&size=728x90&skin=bottom_middle&di=1'></script>`

**for this** `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://newsite...'></script>`

otherwise remove the tag.

Here is my code, but this deletes all script tags, and i want specific tag (mentioned before)

```
function stripScripts(s) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = s;
    var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var i = scripts.length;
    while (i--) {
      scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
    }
    return div.innerHTML;
  }

alert(
 stripScripts('<span><script type="text/javascript">alert(\'foo\');<\/script><\/span>')
);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to remove single script tag then remove the while loop there and identify the correct value of i (position of the script in your html) so as to delete just that

Comment: I don't believe he knows the correct value of `i`, which is why he is asking the question.

Comment: @MattBryant: His concern, as I understand, is about all script tags getting deleted rather than the a specific script tag. I could be wrong though

Comment: I see what you're saying, and that might be a solution for him to use.  I'd obviously recommend against it, just in case he ever wants to add a script tag in the future and have it still work :P

Comment: Yeah, even I wouldn't recommend a hard-coded value of i. My statement says, _identify the correct value of i_; I didn't mean any hard-coding. Well, Actually both are sailing on some boat!! Cheers!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much of the url do you know?

If you know all of it and it won't change:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var i = scripts.length;
while (i--) {
  if (scripts[i].src === "http://site.net/c/banner_s?tenant=AD&selection=5986&size=728x90&skin=bottom_middle&di=1") {
    srcipts[i].src = newSrc; // Your source here
    break;
  }
}
```

If you know some of it won't change:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var i = scripts.length;
while (i--) {
  if (scripts[i].src.indexOf("http://site.net/c/banner_s?...") === 0)  {
    srcipts[i].src = newSrc; // Your source here
    break;
  }
}
```

If the entire url might change, you will want to look into a different solution (ids, placement on page, etc).

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't server side javascript, you're wasting your time. Removing a script element once it's in the page is pointless. Once a script is loaded, it's loaded, you can't "unload" it. Nothing you can do short of navigating to a new URL will change that.

Replacing the src of a script element is similarly pointless, you might as well just load a new element. Replacing the src doesn't unload the script content (see above), it just removes the element.

If you want to load a different script in the page, you must do that at the server.